# Wildcard file matching in XML

Tags: java, regex, xml, xsd, glob

XML file contains `<Wildcard>` tag,

```
       <Wildcard>r_prior*.obj</Wildcard>
```

I want to access file with name r_prior[0-9].obj , there can be a file r_prior_dummy.obj (which I dont need), but with current code it's taking r_ram_dummy.obj also.

Schema code for `<Wildcard>` :

```
    <simpleType name="Wildcard">
      <restriction base="string">
        <pattern value="[^\\/]+"></pattern>
      </restriction>
    </simpleType>
```

I tried putting `<Wildcard>r_prior[0-9].obj</Wildcard>`, but it does not work.

How should I do this?

Comment: Not sure what you want, what you tried and what error or wrong output you got.  This looks all fine to me (the value `r_prior[0-9].obj` matches the regex `[^\\/]+`.)

Comment: I want to select the files which fits the wildcard criteria and put it into zip archive at the end, but using "r_prior[0-9].obj" is not working.

Comment: Just to be clear, what's your goal?   To ***define*** valid values for the `Wildcard` element, or to ***specify*** a value for the `Wildcard` element that some application will interpret to match certain files?

Comment: @kjhughes "to specify a value for the Wildcard element that some application will interpret to match certain files?" -> I have an application, and for selecting one checkbox from tool runs this xml file (having wildcard) in background, and I have a Java code which which iterate through all files in selected directory and copies the file which matches the wildcard to the archive file. now, I want to copy r_prior1.obj, r_prior2.obj, r_prior3.obj... and so on. but not the r_prior_dummy.obj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be two ***independent*** types of pattern matching in play here:

- **Regular expressions**: What XML Schema uses in `xs:pattern`.  More expressive than file globbing; uses `*` to match zero or more of the
  preceding character; `?` to match the preceding character optionally;
  and many more matching constructs.
- **File globbing**:  What libraries often use for filtering lists of files.  Typically less expressive than regular expressions; uses `*`
  to match any character; `?` to match exactly one unknown character
  (in some cases includes 0 unknown characters); etc.

Assuming that you can only change the XML file, you need to check the Java app to see what type of file globbing constructs it supports.  (If you have the source, see what call is being made to filter the list of files and check its documentation.)  You can assume that `*` is supported.   You cannot assume that `[characters]` is supported, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Java source code uses WildcardFileFilter from Apache commons io library to process wildcards, and API says "This filter selects files and directories based on one or more wildcards, the wildcard matcher uses the characters '?' and '*' to represent a single or multiple wildcard characters." is there any way I can use characters also to fulfill my requirements ?

Comment: So `[0-9]` is not supported directly.  Short of changing the Java code, perhaps instead of `r_prior[0-9].obj` you could use `r_prior?.obj`.  Although this would match any single character after `r_prior`, not just numbers, it would at least exclude `r_ram_dummy.obj` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to escape "."

```
r_prior[0-9][.]obj
```

See working exemple here : [RegexR](http://www.regexr.com/3b0ai)

Comment: I am getting this error "The value 'r_prior[0-9]\.obj' of element 'Wildcard' is not valid." may be problem with slash, do we need to change the pattern in Schema ?

Comment: Try that r_prior[0-9][.]obj